# Fourier Transform Time Series in Python

Tags: python, fft

I've got a time series of sunspot numbers, where the mean number of sunspots is counted per month, and I'm trying to use a Fourier Transform to convert from the time domain to the frequency domain. The data used is from https://wwwbis.sidc.be/silso/infosnmtot.
The first thing I'm confused about is how to express the sampling frequency as once per month. Do I need to convert it to seconds, eg. 1/(seconds in 30 days)? Here's what I've got so far:

```
fs = 1/2592000
#the sampling frequency is 1/(seconds in a month)

fourier = np.fft.fft(sn_value)
#sn_value is the mean number of sunspots measured each month
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(sn_value.size,d=fs)

power_spectrum = np.abs(fourier)

plt.plot(freqs,power_spectrum)

plt.xlim(0,max(freqs))
plt.title("Power Spectral Density of the Sunspot Number Time Series")
plt.grid(True)
```

[image: Here is the graph output]

I don't think this is correct - namely because I don't know what the scale of the x-axis is. However I do know that there should be a peak at (11years)^-1.

The second thing I'm wondering from this graph is why there seems to be two lines - one being a horizontal line just above y=0. It's more clear when I change the x-axis bounds to: plt.xlim(0,1).

[image: Graph when plt.xlim(0,1)]

Am I using the fourier transform functions incorrectly?

Comment: FFTs are tricky things.  Remember that an FFT decomposes the signal into sine waves.  Just because your data has a spike every 132 months does not mean you will have an FFT peak there.  I fetched the data, and the plot shows a peak frequency at 25 months.  BTW, you might consider using `np.fft.rfft` instead, since you have real-valued data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on using `np.fft.rfft`! Just to ask - the FFT might not have a peak every 11 years, but `numpy.fft.fftfreq` should return a peak at 11 years right?

Comment: No. `fftfreq` doesn't use the data at all.  It's just computing your x axis values.  It's basically `np.arange()` divided by a constant.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand a bit better now that I've fiddled around with the plot and code a bit too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any units you want. Feel free to express your sampling frequency as `fs=12` (samples/year), the x-axis will then be 1/year units. Or use `fs=1` (sample/month), the units will then be 1/month.

The extra line you spotted comes from the way you plot your data. Look at the output of the `np.fft.fftfreq` call. The first half of that array contains positive values from 0 to 1.2e6 or so, the other half contain negative values from -1.2e6 to almost 0. By plotting all your data, you get a data line from 0 to the right, then a straight line from the rightmost point to the leftmost point, then the rest of the data line back to zero. Your `xlim` call makes it so you don’t see half the data plotted.

Typically you’d plot only the first half of your data, just crop the `freqs` and `power_spectrum` arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the 2 lines now. Just one quick question about the sampling frequency if you don't mind me being daft, but would it be fs = 12 samples/seconds in a year? Or fs = 12samples/1year?

Comment: @jay You have one sample per month, or 12 samples per year. That is your sampling frequency. So instead of Hz (1/s), your units in the plot will be 1/month or 1/year, respectively.

Comment: I see that makes sense - although I am now a bit confused if the units of the x-axis are month^-1 or year^-1, why there would always be such a sharp peak at x=0? Since neither 1/month nor 1/year should be underlying periodicities in the data.

Comment: @jay I’ve edited the answer to be more explicit about sampling frequency and units. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes thank you! I got the plot working as expected. I believe too I understand why there is a strong peak at x=0 - someone suggested to me it's because at x=0 the output is the average value.

Comment: @jay Indeed, the 0 frequency is the constant part of the signal. You can set to 0 frequency to 0, or you can subtract the mean from your signal before applying the transform, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

To set the step for frequencies to one year, determine how many samples represent this duration (12), then take the inverse for parameter `d`:

```
freqs = sf.rfftfreq(n=N, d=1/12)
```

Also, you can improve the frequency scale in some ways:

- Use the period instead of the frequency
- Reverse the scale direction to have small periods on the left.
- Limit the range of frequencies plotted (e.g. first 50 components) in order to see details for components with longer periods. The two cycles are at 11 and 80-90 years.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.fft as sf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tck

# Read values, select columns, convert to numpy array
df = pd.read_excel(fp)
df = df.take([3, 1, 4], axis=1)
data = df.to_numpy()

# Sort by date, extract columns in invidual views, remove DC offset
data = data[data[:,0].argsort()]
year = data[:,1]
spots = data[:,2]
spots = spots - spots.mean()

# Get positive DFT of AQI
N = year.shape[0]
X = sf.rfft(spots) / N
freqs = sf.rfftfreq(n=N, d=1/12) # unit = 1/12 of sampling period

# Plot signal
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,3), ncols=2)
ax=axes[0]
ax.plot(year, spots)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(50))
#ax.grid()

# Plot DFT
ax=axes[1]
extent = 50#N
ax.set_xlabel('period, years')
ax.stem(freqs[:extent], abs(X[:extent]))
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{1/tick:.1f}' if tick!=0 else '$\infty$' for tick in ticks])
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.grid()
```